# How to execute python script on the BaseHTTPSERVER created by python?

Tags: python, http, webserver, cgi

I have simply created a python server with :

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

I had a .htaccess (I don't know if it is usefull with python server)
with:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
Options +ExecCGI
```

Now I am writing a simple python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print '''
<html>
     <head>
          <title>My website</title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <p>Here I am</p>
     </body>
</html>
'''
```

I make test.py (name of my script) an executed file with:

```
chmod +x test.py
```

I am launching in firefox with this addres: (http : //) 0.0.0.0:8000/test.py

Problem, the script is not executed... I see the code in the web page...
And server error is:

```
localhost - - [25/Oct/2012 10:47:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localhost - - [25/Oct/2012 10:47:13] code 404, message File not found
localhost - - [25/Oct/2012 10:47:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

How can I manage the execution of python code simply? Is it possible to write in a python server to execute the python script like with something like that:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(\
    ('localhost', 8123), \
CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
###  here some code to say, hey please execute python script on the webserver... ;-)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Or something else...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track with `CGIHTTPRequestHandler`, as `.htaccess` files mean nothing to the the built-in http server. There is a `CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories` variable that specifies the directories under which an executable file is considered a cgi script ([here is the check itself](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cbdd6852a274/Lib/http/server.py#l951)). You should consider moving `test.py` to a `cgi-bin` or `htbin` directory and use the following script:

***cgiserver.py:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']  # this is the default
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8123), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

***cgi-bin/test.py:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print('<title>Hello World</title>')
```

You should end up with:

```
|- cgiserver.py
|- cgi-bin/
   ` test.py
```

Run with `python3 cgiserver.py` and send requests to `localhost:8123/cgi-bin/test.py`. Cheers.

Comment: Thank for you answer!
I replaced the first line by that:
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler

But I don't understand why you say You should consider moving test.py to a cgi-bin or htbin where are these directory? Is it possible to generate it (with or without root permission?)

Comment: It's not necessary to put `test.py` in a `cgi-bin` dir if you modify the `cgi_directories` list. Setting it to `handler.cgi_directories = ['/']` will allow you to have `test.py` and `cgiserver.py` in the same directory. Otherwise `cgi-bin` and `htbin` are just two directories relative to `cgiserver.py`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes it's work! Thank you so much!!!
I found no site or forum which explain as clearly as you explained!! Thank you!

Comment: @gvalkov Can I somehow serve python script from `http://localhost:8123/`? I tried setting `cgi_directories = ['/']` and putting my python in `index.html` but it complains with `code 403, message CGI script is not a plain file ('//')`. P.s. I'm kinda sorry for digging out the old answer. :(

Comment: Hello @CyprianGuerra. If you insist on using a CGI script for the root resource, you would have to overwrite the `is_cgi` method of `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` and make it set `self.cgi_info = '/', 'your-script.py'; return True`. You might also consider just implementing the `do_GET` method of a `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` subclass, if you don't want to deal with cgi.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)?  It's a lightweight server library that makes this really easy.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '<title>Hello World</title>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The return value, in this case `<title>Hello World</title>`, is rendered has HTML.  You can also use HTML template files for more complex pages.

Here's a good, short, youtube [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZVGwqnjOKjk) that explains it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler approach and use the `--cgi` option launching the python3 version of http server:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

as pointed out by the command:

```
python3 -m http.server --help
```