# Accessing python nltk with php fails

Tags: php, shell, python-2.7, nltk

Im trying to call a python file containing a sentence/word tokenizer from my php file like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('python tokenizer.py $sentence')
```

I've tried single `exec`, full paths to python and tokenizer.py, wrapping `$sentence` in double quotes. But logically, It should not be the problem because calling `print(1)` at the beginning of python the python code **before actually using any nltk packages** makes `$output` equal to '1'. So I came to conclusion that the problem here is the nltk itself, like the path to the modules is not correct or something...

But, calling python from the shell using the same command as above gives me fully tokenized output! **To conclude: looks like when calling python from php magically 'turns off' nltk, while it fully works when executed from the shell.**

Here's the part of the python code I am using:

```
import sys
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sample_text2 = sys.argv[1]
gust = sent_tokenize(sample_text2)
#print(1) here doesn't work, but everywhere above (before calling sent_tokenize) it does.
```

The server's running on CentOS (Linux), I am accessing it via SSH.

**Obvious question: What am I doing wrong here with PHP? Or generally? Any alternatives?**

**EDIT**
As visible in dvhh's answer and its comments, the situation happened because there were two versions installed on the server (2.6 and 2.7), while the `www` user had access to 2.6 and through console, the default version was 2.7. The solution was to change the default python to 2.7 for both cases and to put the nltk modules to one of the dependency folders. (Or append the dependency directory using sys.path.append)

Comment: The most obvious thing is to use python everywhere. But when you say not working, do you see an error?

Comment: nope, even if I set ini_set('display_errors' ,1), nothing. I'd like to use python everywhere, but the whole app is written in php, it's like two weeks of work .

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Have you tried escaping your `$sentence` with `escapeshellarg()` (which is something you should *always* do with `exec` anyway)?

Comment: @e4c5 No, python beginner here, should I?

Comment: No don't want to bring that into the mix at this stage If you had been using a virtualeng it might actually have been a problem. So how exactly is the PHP script executed? by the shell or via web? and what are you doing with the output of the python script

Comment: @lafor like this? `exec/shell_exec('python tokenizer.py escapeshellarg($sentence)'); `
 ?
What is the difference between this and wrapping the sentence in quotes?

Comment: Almost. `shell_exec('python tokenizer.py ' . escapeshellarg($sentence));`

Comment: What is the user executing the php script ? probably the `www` user, and if yes is the `www` user have a path set correctly to `python`

Comment: @lafor just tried that. As expected, no improvements. But thanks for the useful function :)

Comment: OK, just to answer your question about the difference between quotes and properly escaped argument: quotes alone won't save you from a "sentence" like: `foo"; rm -r /; echo "bar` (don't try it, BTW).

Comment: @e4c5 Script is executed via web. I'm just printing the python output, getting it to php `$output` and then `var_dump($output)`, getting a positive value if printing **before** any nltk function and NULL (for `shell_exec`, for `exec` its 0) if printing **after**. The same code worked before but the server's changed.

Comment: @dvhh for now, I'm doing back-end. What do you mean by 'if the `www` user has the path set correctly to `python`'?

Comment: @lafor so if a user put a sentence like this in `$sentence`, it would erase the whole shebang? Wow, thanks for saving my life.

Comment: What about permission of `www` to your lib ?

Comment: @dvhh Can you write an answer with broader explanation? Seems like it can fix the problem but I may require some help to do it.

Comment: What about the permissions to execute your script ?

Comment: i have same problem and i dont pass the sentence to python script but the ID of table row id, and read it from database, but it hangs up when calling the nltk.word_tokenize() but from command line it works

Comment: in my case its not problem of python version... i use eg the mysql module which is only in python3. but it hangs at same place as your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php script is executed by the `www` user.

- You could check if the `python` script interpreter is correctly called, it is usually in one of the directory in the `PATH` environment variable (like `/usr/bin/python`), but the `www` user don't have a `PATH` environment variable set.
  **Solution** specify the whole path to your `python` interpreter in your `shell_exec` call ( also specify the full path to your script when you're at it )
- What about the path the `nltk` library is installed, you could check if the `python` interpreter would correctly look for it by looking at the `sys.path` while running `python` with the `www` user.
  **Diagnostic** : use the `shell_exec` call to run a python script to print the `sys.path` values
  **Solution** : append the library path to the `sys.path` in your python script before the `import nltk`

These would be the most obvious solutions considering the information provided in the question.

Update :
As there is 2 version version of python installed (on that haven't got the library installed ), it is recommended to specify the path to the desired interpreter. The first solution help correct the issue.
In unix like system I would recommend using `which python` command to determine the path of your default python interpreter.

Comment: Ran it, I think I can see where the problem is. Gonna accept when I fix it, thanks!

Comment: If the solution isn't in what I mentioned feel free to post your own answer/solution, or you can comment and I will amend the answer for future reference

Comment: Yes, the problem is there are two versions installed, 2.6 and 2.7. It's a combination of those two solutions that might help I guess. Gotta set the paths manually.

Comment: Clarification: `python --version` returns 2.7.6, the diagnostic you proposed returns all the paths proper for python 2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Please add the information in your question for future reference

Comment: in my case its not problem of not being python3... python version is ok, but nltk.word_tokenize() doesn't work when the python script is called from php script. but it works fine when calling with same command from command line

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Setup a simple python httpserver listening on localhost.  [This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065306/how-to-execute-python-script-on-the-basehttpserver-created-by-python) might help but there are plenty of howtos out there. The advantage is that you don't have the overhead of starting the python interpreter each time the ntlk stuff needs to be executed and you don't have to worry about shell script executions, permissions etc. Disadvantage is a little of extra work and a little overhead.

**Option 2**
Using a task queue. Whatever said and done it's not safe to execute commands from your web facing PHP scripts. If you are already using RabbitMQ or something similar you can use that here. Or else if you are using redis you can use the lpush, rpop methods to make redis behave like a queue. Disadvantage: the result is not immidiately available.

**Option 3**

Anbother strategy for your php script to enter the data into a table and setup your python script to run as a cron job to check the table once a minute. Disadvantage: the result is not immidiately available.

**Option 4**

Your current choice but please make sure that you have escaped the data properly by @lafor if this option is chosen @dvhh 's answer ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't problem of python version but problem (as I soon found) of the nltk_data folder. First I thought it was as permission problem, so I changed the permissions to 777, but that didn't work.

I had to copy the folder.

First you have to find where was the nltk folder installed. You will find it by running python3 command from your bash and then put following lines:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

It will say something like:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
```

Now you know you have it installed eg in /root folder (i had it there).

Then put in your python script which is called by php this:

```
import nltk
print(nltk.data.path)
```

It will output something like: (note the folders are another if you run it from php script or if you call it from command line)

```
['/var/www/nltk_data', '/usr/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

Now just copy your original folder to any of the above folders. I did:

```
cp /root/nltk_data /var/www/nltk_data -r
```

Voila. It works now.