# Hello world in Python in web browser on Mac

Tags: python

I saved this into `hello.py`

```
print("hello world")
```

In the terminal I use this to start a server

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then, when I go to the file in localhost:8000 the browser gives me the code `print("hello world")` instead of `hello world`.

(adding `#!/usr/bin/python` doesn't change anything)

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute python script on the BaseHTTPSERVER created by python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065306/how-to-execute-python-script-on-the-basehttpserver-created-by-python)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SimpleHTTPServer is simply sending the text of your code directly rather than interpreting and running it. You will need to figure out how to configure SimpleHTTPServer to interpret your python code, if this is even possible, or use a different web server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Terminal to create a nano file called helloworld.py

```
sudo nano helloworld.py
```

Then add the code:

```
print "Hello World"
```

Exit the nano file, then run the python file (assuming you're in the directory you just saved your file)

```
python helloworld.py
```

This is much simpler than trying to run it over SimpleHTTPServer, and allows more flexibility with what you can do with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but may be useful for someone. You must write

```
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 --cgi
```

instead

```
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```